# (Android Studio - Kotlin) java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, java-8

I am having a weird issue (I believe something is wrong with my Java JDK setup in android studio).

Context: previously I never had that error before when running my apps on emulators.

Here's my code (see below, it's pretty basic)

I have an basic XML & KT file in Android Studio. everything  will run and compile if I omit the line

`val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)`

It seems that the function is not recognized, but it's a pretty basic standard operation in android kotlin. I noticed that previously Android would suggest an auto complete for it, but now it doesn't apply that auto-complete.

That line is technically correct (again I never experienced the error before but by adding any sort of kotlin function or method. I get this error

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference**

**This is happening for a new project that I create, if I go to open a past project before that issue happened that past project will run without any issue. I don't know what's happening here**

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### MainActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
}
```

I am expecting the emulator to run without any errors.

I am suspecting something is in my android studio setup but I have no idea how to troubleshoot it.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.easyuseapps.calculatormaster, PID: 3562
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculatormaster/com.example.calculatormaster.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3042)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:164)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:677)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:922)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:691)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
        at com.easyuseapps.calculatormaster.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:14)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3562 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You can’t use that function for a property initializer. Properties are initialized when the class is instantiated, which is before it has application info assigned and before you set a content view for it to search for any views.

Comment: If I open a past project that I did before this error started to occur, and delete all the files and replace it with the ones mentioned above, the project will run. But on new project it doesn't. that's what I'm trying to understand here.

This function is actually from the Google Android  Tutorial basically.

Comment: Here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-app-with-button?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-four%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-create-dice-roller-app-with-button#4

Comment: I added the whole error log

Comment: The difference between the tutorial and your code is you put the `val button...` line *outside* the `onCreate()` function, thereby making it a class property. And like I said above, you cannot use `findViewById` in a *property* initializer because properties are initialized too early. Your `button` line is being executed *before* the `onCreate` function is called because all properties are initialized at class instantiation time.

Comment: thanks, yesterday I did realize the mistake too. I also found that using binding instead of findViewById solved the issue too.